# Creating Primary Sub menu's programmatically

Tags: views, 6, routes

I want to display the latest 10 nodes of node type 'ABC' as a sub menu link under my primary menu. Are there any modules for Drupal 6 to help me achieve it.

I have created a view which gives me a latest 10 nodes sorted by creation date. However, I am unable to figure out how to integrate as an submenu links under the primary menu link.

So is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [menu views module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_views):

> **What Menu Views Does**
>
> Menu Views is a utility module. It provides back
>   end support for replacing a standard menu item link with a menu item
>   view. Menu items (in any menu) now have the option of toggling between
>   two different menu item types: link or view. Depending on which option
>   is selected, the appropriate configuration form is displayed on the
>   admin side and the appropriate type of item is rendered on the
>   front-end.

Once you create a submenu, you can attach a view to it. Your title suggests you're asking to do this programmatically. From what i know, i'm not totally sure if that's possible without a lot of headache.

Comment: I am using drupal 6 ...and i have to show 10 node titles of node type 'ABC' as the sub menu links of the primary link, which is the link to their respective nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are expecting is described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/831564). For following the tut you also need to enable [Views build menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_build_menu) module. I haven't tried it but by reading it I'm sure its worth a try.